# QGIS is not displaying geometry features for MySQL table

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, mysql, mysql-spatial

I'm currently working in a MySQL database version 5.7. I've a polygon table that was created using the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE coords(
  ref_geo CHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  geom GEOMETRY NOT NULL
);
```

I was inserting polygons using the following structure:

```
INSERT INTO coords(ref_geo, geom ) VALUES( 'XX_01', ST_GEOMFROMTEXT( WKT ) );
```

**where WKT received the Well-known text without setting the SRID. However all coordinates were in EPSG:4326 (WGS84).*

I can plot those fine in my WebMap application:

[image]

I want to do some visualization in QGIS, but I'm having a harding time doing it. What I did was to create a connection to MySQL Database and then I went to Layer | Add Layer | Add Vector Layer in QGIS. So QGIS can add the geometry table to Layers panel and it recognizes that is a polygon layer
[image] but it doesn't show any feature. I even use the `Set SRID` option QGIS provides to ensure the data was interpreted in EPSG:4326, and then "Zoom to Layer", but still, the shapes are not being displayed by QGIS.

**Funny and important fact**: When I select one feature and click to zoom to it. The QGIS layout zooms to the right place (without showing the feature itself) :
[image]

Therefore, anyone has any hint in how can I make QGIS to display my geometry table data?

---

EDIT:
**[Here](https://github.com/matheussiba/testingpurposes/blob/main/aa.csv) is a subset of my WKT.**

Comment: is it possible that your polygon layer is below the satellite layer?

Comment: No It's not. I check it previously and even removed the satellite layer to make sure, and still, no feature is showing up

Comment: can you add an example of your WKT?

Comment: what spatial reference systems (SRS) are you using? (note: mysql v8+ has better geometry/projection support)

Comment: @IanTurton I just added a subset for the WKT. And Mapperz, I'm aware about mysql v8+ spatial capabilities. Unfortunately, the company's server which I'm working only have access to 5.7 version. I'm not setting any SRID while I'm inserting the polygons via query. But the coordinates itself are in WGS84

Comment: Did you try `ST_GEOMFROMTEXT( WKT, 4326 )` instead of `ST_GEOMFROMTEXT( WKT )`? Not sure if it will change something but worth a try?! Also as your geometry are polygon, turning the wrong side (also called winding) may be your issue cause. Can you give us one WKT sample by editing your question?

Comment: @ThomasG77, a sample of my WKT is added in the last line of my question. Here is the same link I added there https://github.com/matheussiba/testingpurposes/blob/main/aa.csv

Comment: Tested using a more recent version and unable to reproduce unfortunately (MariaDB 10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1). I'm able to display your feature. What is sure is that you also have invalid geometries in your sample (`AA_06` and `AA_03` due to self intersection)

Comment: @ThomasG77 Well, what I did was to export those "invisible features" to a new layer, and it then I could see it. I fixed the geometries using QGIS tools and imported back to mysql using MYSQL Importer Plugin. I re-added the layer and still it's not visible. I tried in a different Windows PC with another QGIS version and the same issue occured. ;/ Although, I could manage to do what I needed, but it still intrigues me why it's not displaying the data.

Comment: check this tread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461400/connection-to-mysql-from-qgis-wont-draw-vector-geometries, i had the same problem and solve it.